# Alternative to "onChange" event with Semantic UI dropdown?

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

This is a dumb question but I've been all over the Semantic UI site, along with searching here and I haven't found a solution.

The gist is: I have been using the code below with a Semantic dropdown list. It works fine – except that I have a table component through which the user can also make a selection (which triggers a function) – and when they do, I update the Semantic dropdown to reflect the current selection . . . and then the `onChange` event fires – so a function is running twice when it doesn't need to.

I tried using `onSelect` but that is apparently not a valid event for a dropdown. I could do some stupid hack to work around this but I'd rather just use a different event. Is there one?

---

```
$(function () {
    $('#productStates').dropdown({
        allowAdditions: true,
        allowReselection: true,
        placeholder: "Select State",
        onChange: function (value, text) {
            if (projectData == undefined) return;                
            loadStateByID(value)
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: onChange: function(value, text, $selectedItem) {
      // custom action
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - solved this. Wish the [Semantic docs](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/usage) were clearer on event handling.

I was trying to prevent a "loading" function from getting called twice when a user clicked on a table cell and the dropdown was updated to reflect the current selection. I update the dropdown using:

```
$('#productStates').dropdown('set selected', activeStateID);
```

The `onChange` event handler captured all changes and so the "load" event would fire twice. Using `action`, the event only fires on a user action, not on setting the  dropdown state through code.

```
$('#productStates').dropdown({
        allowAdditions: true,
        allowReselection: true,
        placeholder: "Select State",
        action: function (value, text) {
            if (projectData == undefined) return;
            $(this).dropdown('set selected', value);
            loadStateByID(text)
        }
    })
```